# Face ID by python open-cv

Tags: python, face-recognition, opencv

I have many photos and I want to find a unique face ID for comparing with another face. Is there an open-cv python solution for generating unique facial ID and comparing that ID with another?

Comment: What do you mean, talking about "Face ID" ? For ecample, dlib operates with 128-D arrays to identify a face on image. You may try [this FR app](https://github.com/bohdansok/Face_Recognition)...

Comment: I just need have a txt or any other simple file which contains some unique known fact IDs to compare with another face quickly.

Comment: If there a way for generating that file I detailed above and compare that file with an unknown face

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once face encodings being built, it takes almost nothing to compare them with pre-defined tolerance (set it 0.0 and you'll have 100% matches only). The esiest way is to use https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition framework and code examples from there. As i wrote above, a face encoding is  an array of 128 float numbers but  it is imposdible to compare them directly. And you can store (save and load for comparetion) that face encodings as pickle or json data file